# How to use illuminate http outside laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use `Illuminate\Http` outside Laravel.

Also, you have to know that I am using my own router.

I just want to use `Http` and `Validation` to get and validate my data.

I tried this code but it is not working:

```php
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture();
$input = $request->all();
```

##### Composer json

```json
{
    "require": {
        "catfan/medoo": "^2.1",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^9.1",
        "razorpay/razorpay": "2.8.4",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^7.2",
        "composer/ca-bundle": "^1.2",
        "abraham/twitteroauth": "^5.0",
        "sentry/sdk": "^3.5",
        "illuminate/view": "^10.33",
        "illuminate/database": "^10.33",
        "illuminate/validation": "^10.33",
        "illuminate/http": "^10.33"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Models\\": "App/Models/"
        },
        "files": ["Helpers/helper.php"]
    }
}
```

But after installing the `Http` package, my router doesn't work.

Comment: When you used `$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture();`, what happened? state what was the result

Comment: when i installed illuminate\http package my router not working and this line code doesn't change anything

Comment: I tried your code snippet in a clean environment where only `illuminate/http` was installed. Both `print_r($input)` and `print_r($request)` worked perfectly for me. Therefore, the values were correct. Have you tried to reproduce the error in a clean environment independent of your project?

Comment: @thalgonoor you cannot say "my router not working", what is not working? Again, what are you expecting to happen? What does "this line code doesn't change anything" mean? Changing what? I do not see anything that should be changed by it, you need to add more details please

Comment: before use http; router response the page view and my contents by after it response blank. i have to try in clean project